# I am working on a navbar but the problem is at width 991px of responsive my brand name comes at the center

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

```css
@media ( max-width:991px) {
  .navbar-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
  }
}

.d-flex {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 130px;
  }
}

.navbar-collapse {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- target="#navbarSupportedContent">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>                     
</button>
    <div>
      <a herf="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <form class="d-flex" action="">
      <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When the page is responsive at width 991px the Brand Name comes at the center of the page but I want to prevent that from happening and keep it in place.